# Search engine for everything illegal, weird, immoral, anti-social and/or anti-government

Tags: search, google-search

I have been a Google user since time immemorial. However, recently, Google seems to filtering results based on its version of acceptable behaviour.

For example, I want to be able to search for these things and get accurate results.

`how to cook meth full video`

`piratebay download photoshop`

Is there a way to force Google to disable its social-engineering policy? Or any alternate search engine that provides such results?

Appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably not Google giving you bad results, nor any real social-engineering policy on their end.  It's simply that we are not in the 90's anymore and people are smarter and more careful.

Companies that allow users to post their own content typically depend on ad revenue and will naturally seek to quell controversy that threatens that, because they need to be open to as many people as possible - alienating large swaths of potential customers with certain types of controversy won't result in people investing in the platform.

And those that do allow such content take action to hide it from Google.

Large software companies like Adobe also are smarter than they were in the 90's and probably actively search Google for cracks and other tools that sidestep licensing and issue DMCAs to get that content taken down.  So serious crackers and pirates are also smarter and don't post such content in places where Google can find it.

So an "evil" search engine publicly accessible and ad-supported like Google couldn't really exist on today's public Internet - content would be gone as soon as it appeared there.

Comment: A very well-reasoned answer. I can see this being the case with `meth cooking` videos. But the case with things like `piratebay` remains open. Users definitely want to find that result in Google, and torrent companies could give a rat's ass about content protection or hiding.

Comment: @antikbd Justice decides that a search result is illegal and Google needs to hide it. Just read news on TorrentFreak and you'll be aware of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off just searching for things like that with the Tor Browser. I think it has a search engine that might be capable of that, but im not completely sure as I haven't actually searched anything like that with it. The Default search engine for Tor is duckduckgo.com, has a similar UI as google.

Comment: Yes been using DuckDuckGo but I am not sure of its algorithm. Google has become a habit.